# MVC3 Razor layout base class from View

Tags: layout, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In MVC with web forms you can set a MasterType like so:

`<%@ MasterType TypeName="FooMasterPage" %>`

Which gives you a reference to the base class of the master page, which you can then use in the View like this:

```
<% Master.title = "foo" %>
```

With Razor we can specify base classes for our Layouts but it seems we cannot access them from our View. Is this really not possible? The only work around I see is using ViewBag/ViewData, which works but adds an extra layer of effort and overhead.

Is there any way to reference the instance of a Layout page's base class from the View?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of any scenario why someone developing an ASP.NET MVC application would ever need to provide a common base type for the master page. This would mean that you are writing something like a codebehind and that kinda sticks in MVC. The fact that you could do this in the WebForms view engine is because this is an heritage from classic WebForms but that doesn't mean that it is something that should be done. There are so many ways to include common functionality in ASP.NET MVC varying from ViewModels, usage of custom HTML helpers, usage of partials, usage of [Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx), usage of razor sections, etc...

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting explaining why you think this answer is wrong.

Comment: how about simple requirement of wanting to wrap a base model as a property. I was doing this in aspx master page for MVC, now in Razor I want to do the same. simply to have call's like @StandardModel.X from master page. Keeps strong typing, and clean view code. Not sure why this would be such a bad thing. Any cahnce you could expand for this e.g.

Comment: I am guessing there's a better way of doing same thing, but I am new to Razor, so comments would be appreciated. Chrs

Comment: Reading this old post is interesting and yes there are scenarios where you want to have a base class for layout views that are shared. When you want and IoC to wire your translation service interface so it can be accessible in razor view. It works gr8 with "normal" views.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether or not you should do something like this in MVC (and I agree with Darin's points) it is simply impossible in Razor, and that is because Razor views get rendered in a single pass starting with the view first. Which layout page will be used is not even known until after the view is done executing.

In contrast, the aspx view engine performs multiple passes where the page/master control tree is first instantiated, then hooked up, then some events occur (which are useful in WebForms but not in MVC) and then rendering happens. It's this concept of the control tree that lets you refer to the Master page from a view page. Razor doesn't have that.

`ViewBag`/`ViewData` are the recommended mechanisms for passing data from views to layouts in Razor.